# Memory ordering when using atomic variable

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

```
AtomicBoolean a = new AtomicBoolean(false);
AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean(false);

Thread A {
   a.compareAndSet(false, true);
   b.compareAndSet(false, true);
}

Thread B {
   print b.get() 
   print a.get()
}
```

From the program snippet above, if both threads ran at the same time, is it possible for Thread B to print true and false? (which means that it sees "b" as true while "a" still remains as false ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible for Thread B to print true and false?

No it is not.  If `b` gets set to `true` then `a` would have already been set to `true` and since `AtomicBoolean` wraps a `volatile`, both fields will be updated and visible with the `get()` calls.  Any access of a `volatile` field ensures that the memory is synchronized as well as all code beforehand is completed == the "happens before" guarantee.

This is, of course, assuming that not other threads are touching `a` and `b`.

With race conditions the possible values printed by `B` are:

- `false`, `false` -- if neither `AtomicBoolean` has been updated
- `false`, `true` -- if `b` is not updated when it is printed but `a` is
- `true`, `true` -- if both `b` and `a` have been updated

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to look at the code. Happened-before guarantee is provided by volatile.

Answer (score 2):

No, `a` is guaranteed to be set to `true` before `b`.  When the values are read it is possible for them to both be `true`, both be `false`, or `a` to be `true` and `b` to be `false`.